# To get the LMT info and all the abbrevations tz in pytz

Tags: python, timezone, pytz

```
import pytz,datetime
tz1 = pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai')
tz1
<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Shanghai' LMT+8:06:00 STD>
>>> str(tz1)
'Asia/Shanghai'
```

1.how can i get the string of   `LMT+8:06:00`  from the output of tz1?

```
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'
dt1 = tz1.localize(datetime.datetime(2002, 10, 27, 6, 0, 0))
print(dt1.strftime(fmt))
2002-10-27 06:00:00 CST+0800
```

2.how can i get all the  abbrevations of timezone which  is composed of  3 upper character such as CST in  `2002-10-27 06:00:00 CST+0800?`

list(pytz.country_names)  get all the  abbrevations of country,list(pytz.all_timezones) get all the  timezones.

```
list(pytz.all_timezones)
list(pytz.country_names)
```

Answer (score 2):

> 1.how can i get the string of  LMT+8:06:00 from the output of tz1?

A single `pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai')` object may correspond to several different `tzinfo` objects (different `tzname()`, `dst()`, and/or `utcoffset()`). The default representation of `tz1` shows one of such objects. You need a concrete date to get the correct tzinfo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Shanghai')
>>> tz
<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Shanghai' LMT+8:06:00 STD>
>>> fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'
>>> tz.localize(datetime(2002, 10, 27, 6, 0, 0), is_dst=None).strftime(fmt)
'2002-10-27 06:00:00 CST+0800'
>>> tz.localize(datetime(1902, 10, 27, 6, 0, 0), is_dst=None).strftime(fmt)
'1902-10-27 06:00:00 LMT+0806'
```

i.e., Asia/Shanghai had +0806 utc offset in 1902.

---

> 2.how can i get all the abbrevations of timezone which is composed of 3 upper character such as CST in 2002-10-27 06:00:00 CST+0800?

If you have an aware datetime object then just call its `.tzname()` method or pass  the date to the timezone explicitly:

```
>>> tz.tzname(datetime(2002, 10, 27, 6, 0, 0), is_dst=None)
'CST'
```

There is no public API to enumerate all possible `tzname()` values for a given zoneinfo timezone. You could use `DstTzInfo._transition_info` attribute, to get the value (without values from a far future (for obvious reasons)):

```
>>> datetime.now(tz).tzname()
'CST'
>>> {tzname for _, _, tzname in getattr(tz, '_transition_info', [])}
set(['CDT', 'CST', 'LMT'])
```